# PostGIS migration to Hibernate 6

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, postgis, hibernate-spatial, spring-boot-3

I'm trying to migrate to Spring Boot 3 (and hibernate-spatial:6.4.1.Final)
So before migration i have following lines in my @Entity describing a column in the table storing a MultiLineString geometry:

```
@Column(name = "multilinestring")
@Type(value = "org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiLineString")
private MultiLineString multiLineString;
```

Naively, I'm converting the @Type to `@Type(org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiLineString.class)`, but this gives an error, because MultiLineString doesn't extend UserType (*incompatible types: Class cannot be converted to Class<? extends UserType<?>>*)

So which class am I supposed to use in this case? Or what am I doing wrong?

Excerpt from my gradle file in case this matters:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'java'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-spatial:6.4.1.Final'
    implementation 'net.postgis:postgis-jdbc:2023.1.0'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6'
    
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the answer was unexpectedly simple:
just remove the @Type annotation:

```
@Column(name = "multilinestring")
private MultiLineString multiLineString;
```

after the upgrade to hibernate 6 (and making sure to include `implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-spatial'`in the build.gradle file), JPA correctly recognizes MultiLineString automatically, so the @Type annotation is not needed anymore.